# Creating collages with smooth transition between images

Tags: windows, image-processing, collage

I have created collages with Microsoft Autocollage before and I like the style of it. It's not like other collages where we can still identify single images by their border. Instead, the images blend smoothly into each other. Hard to explain. It'll not create an image like this:

[image: Usual collage]

but rather like this:

[image: Autocollage]

Of course, it's not just all blurry The pictures are still sharp. Here's a real example:

[image: Real example]

Source: Softpedia

Now, there are a couple of things why I would not use Microsoft AutoCollage again, and a successor should have improved:

- Autocollage does not consider Exif rotation.
- Autocollage selects some pictures randomly from a folder. If you want to be specific, you have to prepare a folder in which you put exactly the photos you want to be processed
- Autocollage randomly detects "interesting" photos and makes them bigger than others. If I think other pictures are more "interesting", I need to hope for the random generator to pick other ones next time.
- Autocollage does a random placement of the images. If I don't like the result, I need to run it again and hope for better results.
- Output options and resolution are limited.

So I want

- Exif rotation support
- Picture selection instead of folder selection
- Scale pictures like I want
- Do a rough layout of pictures like I want

Basically I want a lot more control, except for the blending algorithm.

Other requirements:

- takes JPG as input
- creates a collage with images blending into each other
- creates JPG as output
- support for really large JPG output (like 20.000 pixels)
- Windows 10 support
- max. 100 € one time cost